# Epson XP-245 scanner driver for Ubuntu 18.04 on 64bit (x86_64)

Tags: drivers, 18.04, scanner, epson, simplescan

When visiting http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModuleFromResult and searching for device model "XP-245" and OS "Linux" the driver recommendations are

XP-243 245 247 …
    Printer Driver  Linux
    1.7.0   ESC/P-R Driver (generic driver)     All language
    07-25-2019
XP-243 245 247 …
    Printer Driver  Linux
    1.1.0   Epson Printer Utility   All language
    07-25-2019
XP-243 245 247 …
    Scanner Driver  Linux
    3.57.0  All-in-one package  All language
    07-25-2019

When following the download button hyperlink for the "Scanner Driver Linux", accepting the license agreement and following the "Package Download Page" hyperlink one is redirected to http://support.epson.net/linux/en/imagescanv3.php .

For Ubuntu 18.04(LTS) there is only a 64bit(amd64), no 64bit(x86_64) package option. How can I get the scanner working? Some blog posts mention something that scanners are working with `xsane`, not with `simple-scan`. Is it possible to get the scanner working with `simple-scan`?

Side note: For the "ESC/P-R Driver (generic driver)" drivers there is a package option `epson-inkjet-printer-escpr-1.7.0-1lsb3.2.x86_64.rpm` which can be installed with `alien`. Printing works just fine.

Comment: x86_64 and amd64 are the same thing.  AMD created the x86_64 so amd64 is a valid name for x86_64 (even intel, microsoft & other companies use the *amd64* name.  Historically intel spent effort creating ia64 & non-compatible 64 bit alternatives but the market wanted x86 compatible so amd64 won). amd64==x86_64

Answer (score 1):

`x86_64` and `amd64` are the same thing.

AMD created the x86_64, so amd64 is a valid name for x86_64 (even intel, microsoft & other companies use the amd64 name). Historically intel spent effort creating ia64 & non-compatible 64-bit alternatives, but the market wanted x86 compatible, so amd64 won.

Thus the amd64 package you saw is the correct one for your x86_64 machine.